# How to convert conv3d layer (quantization) in tensorflow lite?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-lite, quantization

I'm using a model containing conv3d layers. I've got an error when converting the model to
tflite saying that conv3d op is neither a custom op nor a flex op.

**code :**

```
model_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "models", "best-model.hdf5")
   # load best weights
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)


no_quant_converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(loaded_model)

no_quant_tflite_model = no_quant_converter.convert()

# write the model to a tflite file as binary file
tflite_no_quant_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "models", "tflite_models", "best-model_no_quant.tflite") 
with open(tflite_no_quant_file, "wb") as f:
   f.write(no_quant_tflite_model)
```

**error :**

['tf.Conv3D' op is neither a custom op nor a flex op](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8p7u.png)

**Question 1 : how to quantize a conv3d layers ?**

I tried to add "f.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS" to the converter supported ops. The code worked
without errors but I don't know if the conv3d layers were correctly quantized or not (to int8).

**Question2 : does adding "Select TensorFlow operators" affect quantization ? if yes how ?**

**edit section**

```
LastValueQuantizer = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantizers.LastValueQuantizer
MovingAverageQuantizer = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantizers.MovingAverageQuantizer

class Default8BitConv3dQuantizeConfig(tfmot.quantization.keras.QuantizeConfig):
  """QuantizeConfig for conv3d layers."""
       
  def get_weights_and_quantizers(self, layer):
    return [(layer.kernel, LastValueQuantizer(num_bits=8, symmetric=True, narrow_range=True, per_axis=False))]

  def get_activations_and_quantizers(self, layer):
    return [(layer.activation, MovingAverageQuantizer(num_bits=8, symmetric=False, narrow_range=False, per_axis=False))]

  def set_quantize_weights(self, layer, quantize_weights):
    layer.kernel = quantize_weights[0]
    

  def set_quantize_activations(self, layer, quantize_activations):
    layer.activation = quantize_activations[0]
    
    
  def get_output_quantizers(self, layer):
    return []

  def get_config(self):
  return {}
```

Comment: If you can use the tf-nightly, there is a bulitin op support for conv3d op. Conv3d layer quantization is not implemented yet even in the tf-nightly. If you want it, please file a feature request at the tensorflow github.

Comment: @JaesungChung thank you for your reply,  I get "error: 'tf.BiasAdd' op is neither a custom op nor a flex op". What should I do, I'm stuck.

Comment: You can enable tf.BiasAdd op through the Select TF option. https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select

Comment: @JaesungChung tanks again, what do you mean by "Conv3d layer quantization is not implemented yet even in the tf-nightly" despite  saying "there is a bulitin op support for conv3d op" ? 
Also, can you recommend any approach (workaround)  for my problem ?

Comment: Conv3d op can not handle quantized inputs so the dequantize op and quantize op pair will be appeared before and after conv3d op to provide float inputs and get the quantized output. Builtin op support does not guarantee that the given op is quantizable. Quantizable ops are a subset of builtin ops. TFLite quantizer will take care of adding the above dequantize and quantize op pair before and after float only op such as conv3d op automatically. The rest of graph, that can be handled by quantizable ops, will be quantized.

Comment: @JaesungChung  if I use the Quantization aware training approach by implementing the class "8 BitConv3dquantizeconfig(Quantize Config)" could it be possible to quantize the model ?

Comment: No, TFLite quantizer won't place 8bit conv3d op since there is no 8bit tensor support from the builtin op. BTW, what does the 8BitConv3dquantizeconfig means?

Comment: I mean When using Quantization aware training approach I can use the interface "tfmot.quantization.keras.QuantizeConfig" to encapsulates all the information needed by the quantization code to quantize a layer like conv3d. So if I create a class (let's call it 8BitConv3dquantizeconfig) that implements this interface would I be able to quantize my model correctly ?
PS : I'll will edit the above description of the problem and add my implementation of this class so you can check it.

Comment: Even though the QuantizeConfig is provided, the TFLite model won't have 8bit quantized conv3d op since there is no such kernel yet. In my understanding, quantization aware training assumes that the quantized kernels with quantized configs will be ready in the TFLite

Comment: @JaesungChung thank you so much for your help